# beamerarticle not defining \inserttitle and co

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm trying to make some notes for my beamer slides, using the `article` class and `beamerarticle`. However, some of the commands I use in my slides --- specifically, the ones that insert previously set values (`\inserttitle`, `\insertauthor`, `\secname`) seem to be missing when using `beamerarticle`.

I've looked briefly at the `beamerbasearticle.sty` and `beamerbasetitle.sty` files (which are being included properly as far as I can tell), but my tex-fu is not strong enough to glean much useful information, except in so far as it appears that the commands I want should be working fine...

Are there some commands I can use to help track this down? (e.g., to confirm that `\inserttitle` is not defined)

Using pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

`slide-notes.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\graphicspath{{../media-inc/}}

\include{tex/util}
\input{tex/presentation}
```

Start of `tex/presentation.tex`:

```
\newcommand{\pubdate}{January 2011}
\newcommand{\reviewtitle}{Monocular Visual SLAM on a Micro Air Vehicle}
\newcommand{\authorname}{John Bartholomew}

\title{\reviewtitle}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{MAV-side}}
\author[\authorname]{\authorname}
\institute[UoB]{University of Bristol}
\date{\pubdate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{center}
\inserttitlegraphic\\[6mm]
\inserttitle\\[8mm]
\insertauthor
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

pdflatex output is:

```
pdflatex -file-line-error-style -halt-on-error slide-notes
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./slide-notes.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerarticle.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasercs.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasedecode.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasearticle.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaseoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasecompatibility.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasefont.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaseoverlay.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasesection.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaseframe.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaseverbatim.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaseframesize.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaseframecomponents.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasecolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasenotes.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasetemplates.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/translator/translator-language-mappings.tex
)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasethemes.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)))
\@input{tex/util.aux}
(./tex/util.tex) (./tex/presentation.tex (./slide-notes.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dictionary-En
glish.dict) <../media-inc/MAV-side.pdf, id=1, 455.10695pt x 257.53128pt>
<use ../media-inc/MAV-side.pdf>
./tex/presentation.tex:17: Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \inserttitle
                 \\[8mm]
./tex/presentation.tex:17:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produc
ed!
Transcript written on slide-notes.log.
make: *** [slides] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I normally do when writing is to do the following:

```
\def\myauthor{Albert Author}
\def\mytitle{The Title}
\author{\myauthor}
\title{\mytitle}
```

This way if I need to change the title or author, I can do it universally. This has the advantage of working in beamerarticle, but also in any other class.

Alternatively, the [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package defines `\thetitle` and `\theauthor` commands that do what you want. And [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) allows reference to the title of a section.