# Accessing short version of title and author in beamerarticle

Tags: beamerarticle

The `beamerarticle` package allows for optional arguments for `\title` and `\author`.
Is there any way to access the short versions (as in `beamer.cls`)?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\title[short title]{Long Title}
\author[A. Nonym]{Anton Nonym}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\makeatletter
\begin{itemize}
  \item Author: \@author
  \item Short Author: ??
  \item Title: \@title
  \item Short title: ??
\end{itemize}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

I am aware of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/beamerarticle-not-defining-inserttitle-and-co), but for compatibly reasons I don't want to define different macro names.

Comment: In article mode (which you get with beamerarticle) the optional arguments are dropped. If you want to keep them you will have to redefine the commands.